# Webclient springboot posting values in map variable to an url using

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap, webclient, postdata

I am a beginner in Springboot .I have some values in my map variable and I need to post it to an external url from Springboot app

```
/**
 * Function to post data to external url
 * @param extracted
 * @return 
 */
private ResponseEntity<String> postData(Map<String, String> extracted) {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("third party base url");
    String response =  webClient.post()
            .uri("/thirdPartyEndPoint")                     
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .retrieve()
            .body(extracted)
            .block();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The variable **extracted** in the above code will be having data like

```
{
"Data 1": "1",
"Data 2": "0000000000000000000000000000",
"JSON Data": "{\"0\":{\"timeStamp\":\"Mon Jan 19 18:15:21 IST 1970\",\"value\":263.76},\"1\":{\"timeStamp\":\"Mon Jan 19 18:15:21 IST 1970\",\"value\":263.76},\"2\":{\"timeStamp\":\"Mon Jan 19 18:15:21 IST 1970\",\"value\":263.76},\"3\":{\"timeStamp\":\"Mon Jan 19 18:15:21 IST 1970\",\"value\":263.76}}",
"Data 3": "80725010",
}

The method body(Map<String,String>) is undefined for the type WebClient.ResponseSpec
```

Can someone point me to how I can do this?The data should be posted as form data. Also how to post it without the escape characters?
[image]

Comment: Is the client expecting the body data in from of Map or a class object that hold the Map object?

Comment: The client expect it as form data. Added Screenshot of Postman in Question. I tried this : but it gives me another error. String response =    webClient.post()
                .uri(readingsUrl)
                .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                .body(extracted)
                .block();           "The method body(Map<String,String>) is undefined for the type Mono<Map>"